# Using JavaScript to match between certain words

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript I want to match everything between the words "user test" but for some reason it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
text = "start user test end user test end"
var matches = text.match(/^user.+est$/g);
```

Need results:

matches[0] = "user test";

matches[1] = "user test";

Comment: Remove anchors  at both ends.

Comment: Probably you need word boundary: `text.match(/\buser.+est\b/g);`

Comment: @esqew I'm used to doing this in PHP with preg_match_all. Switching over to JavaScript made doing this a lot harder. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You can address your issue by utilizing the solution in the duplicate question by adding the `?` quantifier after your `.+` tokens. [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/XUkF2W/1)

Answer (score -2):

**text.match(/(?<=user test)(.*)(?=user test)/g)**